# Firebase Cloud Function gives Error when I try forEach() "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" "

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Stepping through eact customer with a matching email does not work

```
db.collection("organization")
      .doc(glob_orgID)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        const n_email = snapshot.data().owneremail;
        console.log("new email from param2 =" + n_email);
        glob_email = n_email;

        db.collection("customers")
          .where("email", "==", glob_email)
          .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
            var cust = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
              // cust.push(doc.data().customerId);
              console.log("foreach data = ", doc.ref.id);
              return null;
            });
            console.log("Current email is : ", glob_email);
            console.log("Current cust with join : ", cust.join(","));
          });
        console.log("doc exists + " + snapshot.exists);
        return "doc exists:" + snapshot.exists;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error getting customers doc", err);
        process.exit();
      });
    console.log("WTF happended???");  
  });
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the **entire** code of your Cloud Function?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `doc.data()` method on each item inside a map.. Please try:

```js
querySnapshot.map((doc) => {
              console.log(doc.data());
              return null;
            });
```